# Prevent multiple subscribers of a subject triggering part of the subject pipeline for each subscriber in RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, crud, reactive

**intent**

I'm trying to implement a CRUD screen using fully reactive patterns as much as possible (no manual subscription, preferably no `tap` operator, etc...).

**description**

I have two async pipes subscribed to `inventory$` in the template, and a button that sends an object describing a create, update or delete action to `crudActionSubject`.

`performRemoteCRUDAction` does HTTP calls based on the incoming action and `performLocalCRUDAction` updates the local state stored in the accumulator of `scan`.

```js
  inventory$ = 
  
      this.http.get<Ingredient[]>("http://localhost:3000/ingredients").pipe(
        shareReplay(1),
        concatMap(ingredients => 
          merge(
            of(ingredients),  // initial ingredients
            this.crudActionSubject.pipe(  // this pipe runs for each subscriber -- but it should run once for each action sent to the subject
              concatMap((action) => this.performRemoteCRUDAction(action)),
              scan((ingredients, action) => this.performLocalCRUDAction(ingredients, action), ingredients)
            )
          ))
      );
```

**problem**

My problem is, that because of the two async pipes, the CRUD actions trigger the CRUD action pipe twice -- that is, I have two POST requests, two PUT requests, etc...

**question**

How should I construct my pipe to avoid this? I tried searching for RxJS CRUD examples, but most of them use imperative style with/or side effects (e.g. manual subscriptions, `tap` operator, ...) at some point.

I omitted other methods for the sake of brevity. I'll update the description if needed.

**current solution**

Constructing an intermediary subject in an IIFE and subscribing to the pipeline solves the problem, but it's imperative and essentially constructor logic and I'd be happy to see a more reactive approach, if possible.

```
  inventory$ = (() => {
  
      const o = // pipeline as seen above

      const s = new BehaviorSubject<Ingredient[]>([]);
      o.subscribe(s);

      return s;

  })();
```

Comment: Does it work as desired if you put the `shareReplay` after the `concatMap`?

Comment: @BizzyBob yes, thank you. Please provide it as an answer and I'll accept. Pretty obvious in retrospect. Couldn't see the tree from the forest. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what shareReplay is for

```
inventory$ = 

  this.http.get<Ingredient[]>("http://localhost:3000/ingredients").pipe(
    shareReplay(1),
    concatMap(ingredients => 
      merge(
        of(ingredients),  // initial ingredients
        this.crudActionSubject.pipe(  // this pipe runs for each subscriber -- but it should run once for each action sent to the subject
          concatMap((action) => this.performRemoteCRUDAction(action)),
          scan((ingredients, action) => this.performLocalCRUDAction(ingredients, action), ingredients)
        )
      )),
    shareReplay(1)
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest having a different approach, with a more understandable and linear data flow, where you could also do more, like request fresh data from you API on demand.

The idea would be to start with the main entry point as a Subject of [action, data] tuple: `action = new Subject<['create'|'read'|'update'|'delete', any?]>`(), from that perform desired action, and scan different types of results into desired output, also removing the need of `shareReplay` in favor of just `share`:

```
(new Subject<['create'|'update'|'delete', any?]>()).pipe( // can just assimilate 'read' to nothing
  startWith([]),
  concatMap(([action, data]) => performAction(action, data).pipe(
    map((result) => [action, result]))    
  ),
  scan(([, result], [action, actionResult]) => {
    // perform desired local actions with the accumulated value
    // …
    return [, result]; // careful on returning the same structure
  }),
  map(([, results]) => results),
  share()
)
```

Here is a full stackblitz of the code with example requests:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bqh6jp?file=src/main.ts

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Yes, this is much cleaner from a data flow perspective, I've been here, but in this case, I either give up type safety (see: your usage of `any`) or got into a real mess with union types, mappings and null checks...  I guess this is a question of tradeoffs... anyway, yeah, this is a nice, clean pipeline setup.